# Как сделать чтобы посты из сайта отображались в поисковике Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, seo, search, next

Сайт написан на Next.js, есть такой путь: **/catalog/post/[id]**

Мне нужно чтобы посты с моего сайта отображались примерно таким образом:

[image: Пост в поисковике]

Сейчас я пытаюсь ввести содержимое из заголовка  и в поисковике пусто

Вот пост из сайта: https://uniplaytrade.com/catalog/account/be79ef50-eb26-470a-af1c-8f968dee831f/844817b2-eef9-4bcf-a8ba-ba4fd3ddb277

Если не сложно **объясните**, или **скиньте статью**, я даже не знаю как это гуглить правильно

Comment: 1. Используйте search.google.com для вашего сайта. 2. Учтите, что поисковая выдача может обновляться месяц, за секунды там просто так ничего не появится (чтобы немного ускорить, см. пункт 1). 3. У сайта должен быть большой вес, чтобы гугл обратил внимание и начал выдавать что-то по запросам больше (ноунейм сайт даже в гугл толком не попадает, можете сами посмотреть, что у вас в гугле проиндексировалось, наберите в поиске `site:uniplaytrade.com`)